# How to transpile VariableDeclarator to AssignmentExpression?

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin, babel-babylon

I'm trying to take something like `var a = 5;` and transpile it to something like `thing.a = 5`.

Using this code below in my visitor, it tells me `unexpected token .`

```
VariableDeclarator: {
  enter: function (path, state) {
    path.replaceWith( 
      t.assignmentExpression(
        '=',
        t.memberExpression(
          t.identifier('abc'),
          t.identifier('def')
        ),
        t.stringLiteral('xyz')
      )
    )
  }
}
```

What am I not taking into account here?

What's the canonical way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was operating on a Declarator rather than a Declaration. So what I was doing was causing it to compile to something like `var a.4 = 'def'`. Naturally, that fails.